# NavigationView not working properly, NavigationLink Poped automatically random time when the app goes inactive state

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mobile

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tztW1.png)

I am using xcode 14.2 and iOS version 16.2 in my simulator.  In my project i am using Navigation View. It was working fine in iOS 15 simulator as well as mobile. but after updating ios 16+, i am having this type of error:

> "**NavigationLink presenting a value must appear inside a
> NavigationContent-based NavigationView. Link will be disabled.**".

I need to know how to use NavigationView in iOS 16 without any issues.

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

So from your description it's kind of hard to diagnose because you've said it's because of your recent upgrade to iOS 16. This error occurs exactly why it says, you've defined a NavigationLink view outside of a NavigationView. However seeing as how the upgrade caused the issue I am going to assume it has something to do with iOS 16 introducing the NavigationStack.

Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types)

Comment: Your answer is right. But if i am define navigation link outside of navigation view, the navigation is not possible to move next screen. But my side navigation works well.  i don't know how to find the issue.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, however what I am saying is you **should** define the NavigationLink **inside** the NavigationView. However, I think your issue is due to Apple introducing NavigationStacks in iOS 16. I would try switching from a NavigationViews to NavigationStacks and see if it works out for you.